# Keyframes animation in styled-components

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write keyframe, animation in my code but I can't figure it out even after reading the documentation. Please help

````
```const ButtonStyle = styled.div`
.btn_rainbow {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #c53ab4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  &:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, 
#00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 80%, #00C0FF 100%);
    
}
````

}
`;

````
export default function Button() {
    return (
    <ButtonStyle>
        <a class="btn_rainbow" href="#">Click Me!</a>
    </ButtonStyle>
    );
 }```
````

The CSS Keyframe I wanted to add:

````
```@keyframes slidebg {
   to {
    background-position:20vw;
   }
   }
  .btn_rainbow:hover{
   background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 80%, #00C0FF 
 100%);
 animation:slidebg 5s linear infinite;
 }```
````

Answer (score 1):

```css
  


    .glow-on-hover {
        width: 220px;
        height: 50px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: #111;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .glow-on-hover:before {
        content: '';
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left:-2px;
        background-size: 400%;
        z-index: -1;
        filter: blur(5px);
        width: calc(100% + 4px);
        height: calc(100% + 4px);
        animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .glow-on-hover:active {
        color: #000
    }

    .glow-on-hover:active:after {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .glow-on-hover:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .glow-on-hover:after {
        z-index: -1;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #111;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    @keyframes glowing {
        0% { background-position: 0 0; }
        50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
        100% { background-position: 0 0; }
    }
```

```html
   <ButtonStyle>
            <button class="glow-on-hover" href="#">Click Me!</button>
   </ButtonStyle>
```